# How to do a left outer join wtih an include in sub query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a table which I am querying via Entity Framework:

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
    var customizations = context.Customizations.Include("aspnet_Users").ToList();
}
```

However, I want to included another table, "SelectedCustomizations" as a LEFT OUTER JOIN into the above query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are doing something wrong.
From your question it seems that you want to Join "aspnet_Users" table with Customizations and with SelectedCustomizations.

For that you better off with Join() method.

I'd suggest you to get [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/), it comes with loads of examples. Joins are covered too.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and moved the entire query to a Stored Procedure on the database. This solves the problem by avoiding LINQ and ObjectBuilder in the first place.